# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ../#some_id

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to scroll to a div when clicking on an anchor link, but for some reason when using the jQuery selector, it gives me the error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ../#Installation`

Here is the jQuery function:

```
$('a').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

The anchor tag:

```
<a href="#Installation" id="install" runat="server">Installation</a>
```

The div:

```
...
<div id="Installation"></div>
...
```

If I specifically write the div id then it works just fine:

```
$("#install").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$("#Installation").offset().top}, 500);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your code works. check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rprakash_19/fogte4c9/1/)

Comment: @rprakash I forgot to mention I'm using ASP url routing which may be affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

User "var" before animation:

```html
<div id="Installation">I am Installation</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#Installation" id="install" runat="server">Go to Installation</a>
<script>
$('a').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    },500);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't fix the issue.  I just used .replace("../","") on the selector which did it